# python:merge two array in one array

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

How to merge two array in one array?I have two array

```
row1 = [(1, 'Test1'),(2,'Test2')]

row2 = [(1, 'Demo1'),(2,'Demo2')]
```

I want result like this

```
Result = [(1, 'Test1','Demo1'),(2,'Test2','Demo2')]
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would turn the two rows `row1` and `row2` into dictionaries:

```
In [1]: row1 = dict([(1, 'Test1'),(2,'Test2')])
In [2]: row2 = dict([(1, 'Demo1'),(2,'Demo2')])
```

Assuming `row1` and `row2` share the same keys (here, 1 and 2), I would then merge the two rows with the following:

```
In [3]: result = [(k,row1[k],row2[k]) for k in row1.keys()]
Out[3]: [(1, 'Test1', 'Demo1'), (2, 'Test2', 'Demo2')]
```